# Mocking jQuery load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

I have a question regarding mocking of jQuery code. I use Jasmine to unit test my Javascript code but regardless of what tool I use I want to know if it possible to mock a load event?

I have this function:

```
function Update(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4) {
    // do something with arguments
    // push all arguments into an array -> updatedata

    $('#' + 'update').load('update.aspx', updatedata, function(response, status, xhr) {
        AfterTheUpdate(response, status, xhr)
    });
}
```

I need to mock the load functions within the Update function. In case that I can simulate the `AfterTheUpdate` function with the desired values.

Is that possible?

Can anyone perhaps provide me some guides/tutorials which explains how to mock the jQuery load event. Or should I made some modifications to the Update function in order to mock it?

Comment: Did you consider the *manual triggering* of the **load event** on that element?

Comment: @Hitmands what do you mean by manual triggering??

Comment: just in your spec you can do something like that: `$('#'update').trigger('load')`

Comment: Good one, But that does not give me the opportunity to mock the response of my aspx response. It will always returns 404 code. Therefore I needt to mock the load with a specific response. @Hitmands

Comment: You just need to follow the documentation of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

`$('#'update').trigger('load', { status: 200, message: 'ok'});`